# addhandlers event No method overload takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, event-handling, windows-phone

in my windows phone c# application i have this problem

my code:

```
public class mainclass
    {
         private void myfunc()
         {
            BinaryTransfer bn = new BinaryTransfer(params);
            bn.TransferProgress += OnEventProgress();
         }

         private void OnEventProgress(object sender, BinaryTransferProgress e)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("OK");
         }
    }

public class BinaryTransferProgress
    {
        public ulong Progress { get; set; }
        public ulong Size { get; set; }
    }

public class BinaryTransfer
    {
       ...... CODE ....

       public event EventHandler<BinaryTransferProgress> TransferProgress;
    }
```

in this row i have error

No method overload OnEventProgress takes 0 arguments

```
bn.TransferProgress += OnEventProgress()
```

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace This:

```
bn.TransferProgress += OnEventProgress();
```

With This:

```
bn.TransferProgress += OnEventProgress;
```